# Firebase Cloud Messaging v9 issue when using in NextJs v12

Tags: reactjs, firebase, next.js, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am facing an issue when using Firebase messaging (v9). I have a config file to initialize Firebase app.

```js
const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_FIREBASE_API_KEY,
  authDomain: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_FIREBASE_AUTH_DOMAIN,
  projectId: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_FIREBASE_PROJECT_ID,
  storageBucket: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_FIREBASE_STORAGE_BUCKET,
  messagingSenderId: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_FIREBASE_MESSAGE_SENDER_ID,
  appId: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_FIREBASE_APP_ID,
  measurementId: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_FIREBASE_MEASUREMENT_ID,
};

const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
const fbAuth = getAuth(app);
const firestore = getFirestore(app);
const storage = getStorage(app);
const messaging = getMessaging(app);
export { app, fbAuth, firestore, storage, messaging };
```

This raises the following error

[image]

But if I use `getMessaging` inside a component it works.

```js
export async function getFcmToken(uid: string) {
  const messaging = getMessaging(app);
  getToken(messaging, {
    vapidKey: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_VAPID_KEY,
  }).then((token) => {
    if (token) {
      console.log("token", token);
      localStorage.setItem("fcmToken", token);
      //TODO save token to server
    } else {
      console.log("No token");
    }
  }).catch((err) => {
    console.log("An error occurred while retrieving token. ", err);
  });
}
```

- NextJS version: 12.3.1
- Firebase version: 9.17.2
- React Version: 18.2

Answer (score 0):

it happens when the window object is not available . try initializing  the app inside useEffect hook  :

```
useEffect(() =>{
        // Initialize Firebase
        const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
        const messaging = getMessaging(app);
 })
```